# How to start a desktop session without x and also runs a script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, tty, lxde

I have a Ubuntu server with LXDE for development, now how would I create a .desktop file to start a session that doesn't startx but actually logs me into a regular tty1 session and also runs a particular script?

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear for me if you want to log to that server from a different computer, and where is the script that you want to execute.

However it is, you can execute a script via `ssh`.  Let we see it in 2 steps.

**Step 1: Start by command line.**

If it is a local script you can do something similar to

```
 ssh me@MyServer '/bin/bash -s' < /path/to/local_script.sh
```

if it is a remote script you can do something similar to

```
 ssh me@MyServer "/bin/bash /path/to/remote_script.sh"
```

If the computer from which you want to run the script is the server itself you can substitute `MyServer` with `localhost`.

**Step 2 do the `.desktop` file.**

Create a `~/Desktop/MyDesktopShort.desktop` file, and write inside something similar to this

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Version=1.0
>   Exec=/path/to/local_script.sh
>   Name=Let We Run it
>   GenericName=SSH Server
>   Comment=Execute on Server my script
>   Encoding=UTF-8
>   Terminal=true
>   Type=Application
>   Categories=Application;Network;

If the script is on the remote machine write the `ssh` command that you have checked before via  command line.

For more information check [here about .desktop syntax](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/) or even [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).

The `Exec` part is where you can write what you want to execute.
I cannot help you to connect specifically with tty1, but via `ssh` you will be connected with the first `tty` available.
Final Notes:

- you need `sshd` running on the server machine.
- always better `/bin/bash` than a simply `bash` to avoid eventual [trojan horses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_%28computing%29) attacks.